# Google Cloud React App Website works but the express server serving my apis refuses localhost connections

Tags: reactjs, node.js, typescript, express, vite

I am trying to host my website on google cloud vm for which the front end is made in React Typescript and the Backend is serving API's using Express server. I am using nginx as my web server to do a reverse proxy to the frontend as well as the backend. I am able to access the website using the IP address `http://ip_addr:4173/` but for some reason the backend will just refuse to connect to the frontend and give err_connection_refused errors. But, when i try to access the backend like this `http://ip_addr:3005/api/get`, it fetches all the data from my sql database hosted on google cloud. but it wont do the same for the frontend when the frontend tries to call the backend. What could be wrong?
Attaching my nginx conf file, my server.ts file as well.

NGINX Conf File:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

        server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 34.136.141.102;

    # React app
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4173;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    # Express server
    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3005;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

        # Additional configurations for proxying to Express
        # ...
    }

    # Additional configurations for other routes or server blocks
    # ...
}

}


#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}
```

Server.ts file:

```
import cors from 'cors';
import express from 'express';
import helmet from 'helmet';
import { PORT } from '@/config';
import * as db from '@/db';

export const server = express();

server.use(cors());

server.use(helmet({ crossOriginResourcePolicy: false }));

server.use(express.json());

// TODO: logic to combine all teams should be done here in the sql (join operation) instead of current front end implementation
server.get('/:team_id/games', async (req, res) => {
  const team_id = req.params.team_id.replace(/\D/g, '');
  const result: any = await db.query(
    `SELECT
    teams.teamName,
    ${team_id} AS team_id,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN ${team_id} = team1ID OR ${team_id} = team2ID THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS matches_played,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ${team_id} = team1ID AND score1 > score2 THEN 1
             WHEN ${team_id} = team2ID AND score2 > score1 THEN 1
             ELSE 0 END) AS wins,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ${team_id} = team1ID AND score1 < score2 THEN 1
             WHEN ${team_id} = team2ID AND score2 < score1 THEN 1
             ELSE 0 END) AS losses,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ${team_id} = team1ID THEN score1
             WHEN ${team_id} = team2ID THEN score2
             ELSE 0 END) AS goals_for,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ${team_id} = team1ID THEN score2
             WHEN ${team_id} = team2ID THEN score2
             ELSE 0 END) AS goals_against
    FROM games
    JOIN teams ON ${team_id} = teams.id
    GROUP BY teams.teamName;`
  );
  res.send(result[0]);
});

server.post('/games', async (req, res) => {
  const { team1ID, team2ID, team1Score, team2Score, gameTime } = req.body;
  const query = 'INSERT INTO games (team1ID, team2ID, score1, score2, gameTime) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
  const values = [team1ID, team2ID, team1Score, team2Score, gameTime];
  const result = await db.query(query, values);
  res.send(result);
});

server.get('/teams', async (_req, res) => {
  const result = await db.query('SELECT * FROM teams;');
  res.send(result);
});

// schedule api's start here

server.get('/api/get', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const sqlGet = 'SELECT * FROM schedules';
    const result = await db.query(sqlGet);
    res.send(result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
  }
});

server.post('/api/post', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { DATE, TEAM1, TEAM2, TEAM3, TEAM4 } = req.body;
    const sqlInsert = 'INSERT INTO schedules (DATE, TEAM1, TEAM2, TEAM3, TEAM4) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
    const result = await db.query(sqlInsert, [DATE, TEAM1, TEAM2, TEAM3, TEAM4]);
    res.send(result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
  }
});

server.delete('/api/remove/:srno', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { srno } = req.params;
    const sqlRemove = 'DELETE FROM schedules WHERE srno = ?';
    const result = await db.query(sqlRemove, srno);
    res.send(result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
  }
});

server.get('/api/get/:srno', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { srno } = req.params;
    const sqlGet = 'SELECT * FROM schedules WHERE srno = ?';
    const result = await db.query(sqlGet, [srno]);
    res.send(result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
  }
});

server.put('/api/update/:srno', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { srno } = req.params;
    const { DATE, TEAM1, TEAM2, TEAM3, TEAM4, passcode } = req.body;

    // Validate passcode logic here

    const sqlInsertPasscode = 'INSERT INTO passcode (passcode) VALUES (?)';
    await db.query(sqlInsertPasscode, [passcode]);

    const sqlUpdate = 'UPDATE schedules SET DATE = ?, TEAM1 = ?, TEAM2 = ?, TEAM3 = ?, TEAM4 = ? WHERE srno = ?';
    const updateResult = await db.query(sqlUpdate, [DATE, TEAM1, TEAM2, TEAM3, TEAM4, srno]);

    res.send(updateResult);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
  }
});

// app.get('/', (req, res) => {});

// schedule apis end

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on Port ${PORT}`);
});
```

The firewall rules have already been updated on the cloud console for both `default-allow-internal` and for `http` and `https` to allow everything (will update the firewall rules later once i figure this out).
Any suggestions or ideas as to what could be the issue?

I have already tried to add the `0.0.0.0` to my server.ts file and it will still not work. I have also tried to adjust the firewall rules but it won't budge.

Here's the error what Edge Developer Console gives me

```
3f2f37.js:1 
        
        
        GET http://localhost:3005/teams net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
Wi @ 3f2f37.js:1
(anonymous) @ 3f2f37.js:1
z @ 3f2f37.js:1
B @ 3f2f37.js:1
setTimeout (async)
n @ 3f2f37.js:1
requestAnimationFrame (async)
W @ 3f2f37.js:1
hn.diffed @ 3f2f37.js:1
b @ 3f2f37.js:1
p @ 3f2f37.js:1
b @ 3f2f37.js:1
p @ 3f2f37.js:1
b @ 3f2f37.js:1
p @ 3f2f37.js:1
b @ 3f2f37.js:1
(anonymous) @ 3f2f37.js:1
u @ 3f2f37.js:1
setTimeout (async)
c @ 3f2f37.js:1
i.setState @ 3f2f37.js:1
r.__c.r.__ @ 3f2f37.js:1
(anonymous) @ 3f2f37.js:1
push @ 3f2f37.js:1
(anonymous) @ 3f2f37.js:1
(anonymous) @ 3f2f37.js:1
Ze.onClick @ 3f2f37.js:1
v @ 3f2f37.js:1
3f2f37.js:1 
        
        
        Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at Wi (3f2f37.js:1:159282)
    at Object.__ (3f2f37.js:1:159531)
    at z (3f2f37.js:1:10968)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at B (3f2f37.js:1:10658)
Wi @ 3f2f37.js:1
(anonymous) @ 3f2f37.js:1
z @ 3f2f37.js:1
B @ 3f2f37.js:1
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ 3f2f37.js:1
z @ 3f2f37.js:1
B @ 3f2f37.js:1
setTimeout (async)
n @ 3f2f37.js:1
requestAnimationFrame (async)
W @ 3f2f37.js:1
hn.diffed @ 3f2f37.js:1
b @ 3f2f37.js:1
p @ 3f2f37.js:1
b @ 3f2f37.js:1
p @ 3f2f37.js:1
b @ 3f2f37.js:1
p @ 3f2f37.js:1
b @ 3f2f37.js:1
(anonymous) @ 3f2f37.js:1
u @ 3f2f37.js:1
setTimeout (async)
c @ 3f2f37.js:1
i.setState @ 3f2f37.js:1
r.__c.r.__ @ 3f2f37.js:1
(anonymous) @ 3f2f37.js:1
push @ 3f2f37.js:1
(anonymous) @ 3f2f37.js:1
(anonymous) @ 3f2f37.js:1
Ze.onClick @ 3f2f37.js:1
v @ 3f2f37.js:1
3f2f37.js:1 
        
        
        GET http://localhost:3005/teams net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
Wi @ 3f2f37.js:1
(anonymous) @ 3f2f37.js:1
z @ 3f2f37.js:1
B @ 3f2f37.js:1
setTimeout (async)
n @ 3f2f37.js:1
requestAnimationFrame (async)
W @ 3f2f37.js:1
hn.diffed @ 3f2f37.js:1
b @ 3f2f37.js:1
p @ 3f2f37.js:1
b @ 3f2f37.js:1
p @ 3f2f37.js:1
b @ 3f2f37.js:1
p @ 3f2f37.js:1
b @ 3f2f37.js:1
(anonymous) @ 3f2f37.js:1
u @ 3f2f37.js:1
setTimeout (async)
c @ 3f2f37.js:1
i.setState @ 3f2f37.js:1
r.__c.r.__ @ 3f2f37.js:1
(anonymous) @ 3f2f37.js:1
push @ 3f2f37.js:1
(anonymous) @ 3f2f37.js:1
(anonymous) @ 3f2f37.js:1
Ze.onClick @ 3f2f37.js:1
v @ 3f2f37.js:1
3f2f37.js:1 
        
        
        Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at Wi (3f2f37.js:1:159282)
    at Object.__ (3f2f37.js:1:159550)
    at z (3f2f37.js:1:10968)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at B (3f2f37.js:1:10658)
```

and here is the error on the schedule page

```
3f2f37.js:1 
        
        
        GET http://localhost:3005/api/get net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
(anonymous) @ 3f2f37.js:1
xhr @ 3f2f37.js:1
Et @ 3f2f37.js:1
request @ 3f2f37.js:1
zo.<computed> @ 3f2f37.js:1
(anonymous) @ 3f2f37.js:1
n @ 3f2f37.js:1
(anonymous) @ 3f2f37.js:1
z @ 3f2f37.js:1
B @ 3f2f37.js:1
setTimeout (async)
n @ 3f2f37.js:1
requestAnimationFrame (async)
W @ 3f2f37.js:1
hn.diffed @ 3f2f37.js:1
b @ 3f2f37.js:1
p @ 3f2f37.js:1
b @ 3f2f37.js:1
p @ 3f2f37.js:1
b @ 3f2f37.js:1
p @ 3f2f37.js:1
b @ 3f2f37.js:1
(anonymous) @ 3f2f37.js:1
u @ 3f2f37.js:1
setTimeout (async)
c @ 3f2f37.js:1
i.setState @ 3f2f37.js:1
r.__c.r.__ @ 3f2f37.js:1
(anonymous) @ 3f2f37.js:1
push @ 3f2f37.js:1
(anonymous) @ 3f2f37.js:1
(anonymous) @ 3f2f37.js:1
Ze.onClick @ 3f2f37.js:1
v @ 3f2f37.js:1
3f2f37.js:1  Uncaught (in promise) ot {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
```

Comment: can you try using external ip, not localhost?